# Setting time field to current time in post gres

Tags: postgresql, go

So I'm pretty new to Post gres and am trying to set the value of a time field to be the current time.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET updated_at = now(),
WHERE id = :id
```

I'm executing this with golang and the above syntax errors.

How do I enter the current time into the updated_at time field?

Comment: Remove the comma before the `where` (or after the `now()`).

Comment: Always, **always** show the exact error text. "Syntax error" is not a mystery code. It usually tells you where the error is and what is wrong. In this case it would've output: `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"` `LINE 3: WHERE id = 1;`. So you know to look around there, just before/after the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As point out by someone you have an extra `,` that is causing the issue.
You can form the string correctly (`query` in the below example)and pass it to the db API.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    name := "table_name"
    id := "table_id"
    query := fmt.Sprintf("UPDATE %s SET update_at = %q WHERE id = %s", name, time.Now(), id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned

> You want to set the value of a time field as current time

You can try this, `Now()` provides current DateTime. After casting as `Time` we can get `currenttime`

```
UPDATE table_name
SET updated_at = now()::TIME
WHERE id = _id
```

Alternately you can try

```
UPDATE table_name
    SET updated_at = current_time --gives you current time with time zone
    WHERE id = _id
```

please refer 
 https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html for more details.

Hope it works for you.